pip dependencies from env yaml file missed during building docker container
I have the following conda environment YAML file :
name: someapp
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - flask=2.2.2
  - pandas=1.5.3
  - pip=23.0.1
  - python=3.11.3
  - pip:
      - psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
      - requests==2.32.3
prefix: /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/someapp

And I would like this env to be created when building my docker container (for a Flask app) but I have a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' error when launching the server.py file where I import requests with the following DockerFile :
FROM continuumio/miniconda3

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends \
    && apt-get clean

WORKDIR /app/services/back_end/

COPY ./environment.yml ./environment_server.yml
RUN conda env create -f ./environment_server.yml

# added line to try to install but doesn't work
RUN /bin/bash -c "source activate someapp && pip install requests" 

RUN echo "source activate someapp" > ~/.bashrc
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/someapp/bin:$PATH

EXPOSE 6969

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "server.py"]


Environment variables set in RUN commands don't persist, and most paths to running things in Docker don't read shell dotfiles like .bashrc.  You need to activate the environment in your CMD or ENTRYPOINT.  The linked question has some sample setups specifically for conda.

Thank you, i had already seen this post but I took the second answer as it seems to work at the time

To run conda with your environment you should use conda command, but in your case you should change entrypoint for the container.
It should looks like
ENTRYPOINT ["conda", "run", "--no-capture-output", "-n", "someapp", "python", "server.py"]

Check the command spec here
